# Trying to get administrator consent for Microsoft Graph API access

Tags: httprequest, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm following this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/auth-v2-service

under step 3, when I try to enter:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=xxx&state=12345&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient

into the browser in order to get admin consent, 
Microsoft returns:

"AADSTS500201: We are unable to issue tokens from this API version for a Microsoft account. Please contact the application vendor as they need to use version 2.0 of the protocol to support this."

instead of signing me in.

The Grant admin consent button is missing in my view:

[image]

I would highly appreciate your response!

Dan

Answer (score 2):

I didn't reproduce your issue by following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/auth-v2-service). Here are the main steps for your reference.

1.Register an application in Azure portal. I noticed that you were using **common** as the value of tenant parameter. So I registered a multi-tenant application.

[image]

2.Add an application permission.

[image]

3.Get administrator consent. You can do this at the Azure portal by clicking **Grant admin consent** button.(See the screenshot in step2). Here I used the same way as yours. Remember to use the tenant admin account to login. Then I can see the consent window.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot Tony!!
But this 'Grant admin consent button' is not shown in my console..
Do u know why that could be?

Comment: @DaniElHahn For non-admin user, the 'Grant admin consent' button will be grey.

Comment: @DaniElHahn Do you have any other concerns regarding this?